# computer to computer connection

Tags: javascript, spring, server, connection

VScode uses js and IntelliJ uses Spring. VScode is used in the front end and Spring is used in the back end. Each of them has their own computer, and I am trying to make a fetch connection from the vscode side, but I get ip and server errors. I tried many ways to solve it, but it didn't work. Is there anything I need to set up when I try to connect from another place? Both are using mac. I am a beginner in programming. I'm not good at English, but I'm asking a question on Stack Overflow, which has the most information by translating it. help!

I also set the headers using fetch, and even though I turned off all the firewalls, I can't connect from other places.

Comment: does your browser console have any CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing): erros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the content above all , there is no technical description about env or  major question. so here is some  suggestion  that may be potential helpful for  you .

###### NetWork

1. Checkout  your network is  accessiable ,  try to `ping` the  target ip

###### Code Error

http in spring

2. Spring or some else framework occur error . please  show more about response code or backend error stack

###### Cors

3. if the network resource is not in current domain application , google the cors , lots of Solutions waiting for you